# Implement "Navigation bar" for custom editor

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsx, vs-extensibility, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

When registering a custom language service extension, Visual Studio creates a new options entry for the language within the `Text Editor` node (in the Visual Studio options dialog). Beneath that node two default nodes are created named `General` and `Tabs`, whereby the `General` tab contains statement completion and display settings...

In the `Dispay` group there are three options; one of them is the `Navigation Bar` checkbox (which shows/hides the editor´s navigation bar). For my custom language service, this option is disabled. Of course, it´s not implemented yet.

[image]

I would like to know, what I have to do, to provide a navigation bar for my custom editor... I guess that there is a certain interface I have to implement in the editor´s factory, or the language service package must export a certain MEF component, or, or, ...

Comment: It turns out you actually do need to register an idle timer to get this functionality to perform as it should.  Once you do that, you will get calls to `OnSynchronizeDropdowns` and also get `ParseSource` calls with a `ParseReason` of `Check` (needed if you want to display errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jon Senchyna´s answer guided me into the right direction. The `OnSynchronizeDropdowns` method gets never called (the SDK documentation is just wrong in that case). What did the final trick was to override at least `GetComboAttributes`, `GetEntryAttributes` and `GetEntryText` to get text-only items for both combo boxes...

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public sealed class CustomTypeAndMemberDropdownBars : TypeAndMemberDropdownBars
{
    private readonly IList<string> declarations;

    private readonly IList<string> members;

    public CustomTypeAndMemberDropdownBars(
        LanguageService languageService, 
        IVsTextView view)
        : base(languageService)
    {
        // TODO: initialize declarations and members from the given text view...
        this.declarations = ...
        this.members = ...
    }

    private enum ComboIndex
    {
        Types = 0, 

        Members = 1
    }

    public override int GetComboAttributes(
        int combo, 
        out uint entries, 
        out uint entryType, 
        out IntPtr imageList)
    {
        entries = 0;
        imageList = IntPtr.Zero;

        entryType = (uint)DROPDOWNENTRYTYPE.ENTRY_TEXT;

        var comboType = (ComboIndex)combo;
        switch (comboType)
        {
            case ComboIndex.Types:
                entries = (uint)this.declarations.Count();
                break;

            case ComboIndex.Members:
                entries = (uint)this.members.Count();
                break;
        }

        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    public override int GetEntryAttributes(
        int combo, 
        int entry, 
        out uint fontAttrs)
    {
        fontAttrs = (uint)DROPDOWNFONTATTR.FONTATTR_PLAIN;

        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    public override int GetEntryText(
        int combo, 
        int entry, 
        out string text)
    {
        text = null;
        var comboType = (ComboIndex)combo;
        switch (comboType)
        {
            case ComboIndex.Types:
                text = this.declarations[entry];
                break;

            case ComboIndex.Members:
                text = this.members[entry];
                break;
        }

        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    public override bool OnSynchronizeDropdowns(
        LanguageService languageService, 
        IVsTextView textView, 
        int line, 
        int col, 
        ArrayList dropDownTypes, 
        ArrayList dropDownMembers, 
        ref int selectedType, 
        ref int selectedMember)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you set `myLanguagePreference.ShowNavigationBar` to `true` in your `LanguageService`'s `GetLanguagePreferences` function, does `OnSynchronizeDropdowns` get called?

Comment: Also, how do you proffer your service?  I found two ways on the internet that it was done.  One was was to add a `ServiceCreatorCallback`.  The other way was to register it via the `SOleComponentManager`.  I found that using the first way caused a lot of my `LanguageService`s functionality to not work, including the navigation bar.

Comment: Forcing the `ShowNavigationBar` property to `true` in the language preferences does not cause a call of the `OnSynchronizeDropdowns` method.

Comment: I register the language service in the `Initialize` method of my package. I am casting the current `VsPackage` instance to `IServiceContainer` and then call `AddService` to promote the language service instance.

Comment: Ahh, thought so.  For some reason, when I proffer the service that way, the dropdowns don't work (not does naything else aside from syntax highlighting).  When I use the old `SOleComponentManager` method of proferring, everything works.

Comment: I opened a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055112/issues-proferring-language-service) for why the navigation bar (and many other pieces of functionality) only works when proffering a service "the old way".

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following steps should be what you need:

1. In your `Package` class, set the `ShowDropDownOptions` property to true in the `ProvideLanguageService` attribute
2. Create a class that implements `TypeAndMemberDropdownBars`
3. In your `LanguageService` class, implement the `CreateDropDownHelper` function and have it return an instance of your `TypeAndMemberDropdownBars`

Comment: This allows me to show and hide the navigation bar, but the combo boxes always remain empty; the `OnSynchronizeDropdowns` method of my `TypeAndMemberDropdownBars` implementation is never called.

Comment: I had the same issue before.  I don't have access to the code right now, but I'll take a look at it tomorrow and let you know what I did.

Comment: Can you update your question with your implementation of `CreateDropDownHelper`?

Comment: I think I found my missing step.  In my implementation of `GetLanguagePreferences`, I had to force the `ShowNavigationBar` property to `true`.

Comment: From what I can tell, `ShowDropDownOptions ` toggles whether or not the "Navigation bar" option is selectable in the Options GUI, but whether or not it is checked is stored in the [registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166421(v=vs.100).aspx)